# Prove that a matrix $A$ is nilpotent iff for all $v$ there is $k$ such that $A^k v=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, definition, nilpotence

For nilpotent matrices, I was given two equivalent definitions. Let $A \in End(V)$.

1. $\forall v \in V$ there exists $k \geq0$ such that $A^k v = 0$.
2. there exists $k \geq 0$ such that $\forall v \in V$, $A^kv=0$.

They seem to be equivalent but i don't know how to show it formally.

Comment: I think that the combination of these two implies that there exists $k\geq 0$ such that $A^k = 0$. Actually, the second alone implies that $A^k = 0$ (the kernel of $A^k$ is the whole space, hence the matrix is zero). Then this fact implies 1.

Comment: The second condition implies the first. However, the first condition only implies the second in certain cases, like when $V$ is finite dimensional. (Pick a basis, the proof is quite easy). If $V$ is infinite-dimensional, these two concepts are different: the first is called “locally nilpotent” and the second is called “nilpotent”.

Answer (score 2):

Let $e_1,e_2,..,e_n$ be  basis. Under 1) there exists $k_1,k_2,..,k_n$ such that $A^{k_i}e_i=0$ for each $i$. It follows that $A^{k}e_i=0$ for each $i$ if $k$ exceeds each of the numbers $k_1,k_2,...,k_n$. Since $e_1,e_2,..,e_n$ is  basis it follows that $A^{k}v=0$ for all $v$ for such $k$.

Answer (score 0):

### $1\Rightarrow2$

You have $A=0$ iff $Av=0$ for all $v$ in a basis. Then take an orthonormal basis $\{e_1,...,e_n\}$.
For each $e_j$ there is by hypothesis some $k_j\in\mathbb N$ such that $A^{k_j}e_j=0$. Thus if you take the biggest of these $k_j$ you obtain some $k$ such that $A^k e_j=0$ for all $j=1,...,n$, and therefore $A=0$.

### $1\Leftarrow2$

If $A^k=0$ then $A^k v=0$ for all $v$, and therefore the statement is true taking the same $k\in\mathbb N$ for each vector $v$.